# How to get content of tags in array?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce and a function returns item data in the below format

```
<dl class="variation">
<dt>options:</dt><dd>redwood-120mm-x-28mm</dd>
<dt>length:</dt><dd>3.6</dd>
<dt>linear metres:</dt><dd>500</dd>
</dl>
```

I want to input this data into an array, like the following;

```
array("options:" => "redwood-120mm-x-28mm", "length:"=> "3.6", "linear metres:" => "500");
```

How do  i do this?

This is the function:

```
global $woocommerce;
     foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        echo $woocommerce->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item );

     }
}
```

Comment: don't you mind posting your function please?

Comment: See edit, i've added the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by regular expression, maybe you want to give a shot for DOM in PHP.

My explanation is in the code in comments.

```
//String to parse
$string = '<dl class="variation">
<dt>options:</dt><dd>redwood-120mm-x-28mm</dd>
<dt>length:</dt><dd>3.6</dd>
<dt>linear metres:</dt><dd>500</dd>
</dl>';

//Keys, you want to find
$keys = array('options', 'length', 'linear metres');

//The result array
$result = array();

//Loop through the keys
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    //Insert the result into the result array
    $result[$key] = getValueByKey($key, $string);
}

//Show results
var_dump($result);

function getValueByKey($key, $string) {
    //The pattern by key
    $pattern = '/<dt>' . $key . ':<\/dt><dd>(.*?)<\/dd>/i';

    //Initialize a match array
    $matches = array();

    //Do the regular expression
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    if (!empty($matches[1])) {
        //If there are match, then return with it
        return $matches[1];
    }
    //Otherwise return with false
    return false;
}
```

**Output is:**

```
array (size=3)
  'options' => string 'redwood-120mm-x-28mm' (length=20)
  'length' => string '3.6' (length=3)
  'linear metres' => string '500' (length=3)
```